# Ruby get the size in bytes of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to obtain the size in bytes of the content of an array (items) in ruby.

I fill my array like this:

```
  @records.each do |record|
    items << { :table => table, :id => record.id, :lruos => record.updated_at }
  end
```

In fact, I want to force sending the Content-Length of this array when I serialize it in JSON:

```
respond_to do |format|
  #response['Content-Length'] = items.to_s.size
  format.json { render :json => { :success => "OK", :items => items } }
end
```

So any idea to do this could be interesting.
(for a reason I don't know the content length is not sent, so I want to force it)

I use Rails 3.0.5.

Comment: Why not instead first serialize it and then get the size of the serialized string? The serialized JSON is probably larger than the array so your approach wouldn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like WTP said, you probably intend on returning the size of the JSON representation instead of  ruby representation of the array, because the JSON is the actual response to the browser. You can do this by encoding beforehand (yielding a string) and then checking its size.

```
response['Content-Length'] = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(items).size
```

[More about JSON serialization and rails](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/)

Comment: I understand what you said and the way to serialize, but adding your line, I have this error: Read error: #<NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 241700:Fixnum>

Comment: The problem is the "size". I tried with "length" but same error.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why that is happening. Can you build a record hash and serialize it in the Rails console? ActivSupport::JSON should be able to serialize pretty much anything -- it handles all Rails objects and primitives, and also should call to_s on objects that doesn't have to_json. You could try serializing individual fields of the hash (i.e. encode( record.updated_at), encode(table), encode(record.id) etc until you find an error -- then you know what isn't being supported.

Comment: The fact is the ActiveSupport:JSON works properly. This is the kind of response I have:     `[{"id":"1","table":"countries","lruos":"2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":"10","table":"countries","lruos":"2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":"100","table":"countries","lruos":"2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"}]` with `response['Content-Length'] = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(items)` Only asking the size is a problem and return the error above ( Read error: #<NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 241700:Fixnum>)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can also do this by `item.to_json.bytesize`. This will give you the size of JSON string that is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are still wondering - I found this to work

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(items).size.to_s
```

Which while its many years later - may help someone.